# How to add an Divider in Lists Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I add a divider in this list like to divide them all from a small horizontal line [Screen in phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqc63.png)

Also How can I add a text in the space on Top. When I tried to add an text there I get an error. My code is below,

```
body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  new ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 250.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                    new Text("Hello"),
                    controller: controller,
                    children:
                      List.generate(100, (int i){
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/avatar.jpg"),
                          ),
                          title: Text("List Index is $i"),
                        );
                      }),
                  ),
```

Comment: you can use ```ListView.separated()```

Comment: Please add the error you got when adding a text above your list.

Comment: This question should be improved to be helpful for others. Here is a good resource on how to write a good question [ask] and the importance of a minimal reproducable example [repro]. Community members please use "flag"/"close" votes to improve this question.

Comment: I added the ```ListView.separated()``` I got an error as "Error: No named parameter with the name 'children'.". And when I add the text I got an error as "Error: No named parameter with the name '#1'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want but the easiest one is shown below:-

```
return TabBarView(
        children: [
ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/avatar.jpg"),
        ),
        title: Text("List Index is $index"),
      ),
    ),]);
```

Comment: Which point should I add it on my code. It gives me an error because it's TabBarView

Comment: Nope I just checked with tabBarView. It is working completely fine and not causing any error. Can you please mention the error that you get.

Comment: "Error: Unexpected token 'return'". Can You like add the code from the TabBarView onwards?